# How to monitor changes in a webpage in WebView2

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, webview2, winui-3

I have a WebView2 with a webpage opened. This webpage can change at any moment and will automatically update.
I need to monitor this page to capture the moment when it updates and execute a given method.

This is an example of the source code of the webpage:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-divProcessandoPagina" style="display: none; z-index: 1004; outline: 0px; height: auto; width: auto; top: 397px; left: 501px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; position: fixed;">
```

When the style "display" changes from "none" to "block", I have to execute a method in the application.

I've tried the NavigationStarted and NavigationCompleted events but the webpage updates just some parts of it's code, so, these events aren't triggered.

The problem is how can I monitor the webpage to when it changes, I can execute the method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built-in function. But, if you are just looking for a way to delay an action until the page changes, you could do this:

```
//get the initial source code - credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431464/vb-net-webview2-how-can-i-get-html-source-code
var thesource = await [WEBVIEW2 VARIABLE].ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");

//decode it from unicode notation - credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string
thesource = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(thesource);

//make another variable that equals the source code so that you can compare
var thesource2 = thesource;

//keep updating source code until it changes
while (thesource == thesource2) {
    thesource2 = await [WEBVIEW2 VARIABLE].ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
    thesource2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(thesource2);
}

//insert desired code here
Console.WriteLine("code changed");
```

[image: GIF of the result]

If you wanted to specifically wait until the `display` property of the `div` tag you attached above switches from `none` to `block` and not any other source code changes, you could replace the `while` loop condition with your own.